# How do you delete a Canvas text object?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

This is for example a create_text:

```
self.__canvas.create_text(350, lineVotes, text=str(likesPrinted),
                          font=("calibri", 30), fill="#66FF99", anchor=E)
```

How could I delete this with a button?

Answer (score 14):

One way to do it is by using the [object ID](http://web.archive.org/web/20190414003210id_/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/canvas-oid.html) that all `Canvas` object constructors return:

```
self.text_id = self.__canvas.create_text(350, lineVotes,
                                         text=str(likesPrinted),
                                         font=("calibri", 30),
                                         fill="#66FF99", anchor=E)
```

Then afterwards you can use the `Canvas` object's [`delete()`](http://web.archive.org/web/20190414003210id_/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/canvas-methods.html) method like this:

```
self.__canvas.delete(self.text_id)
```

Another way is to attach a [tag](http://web.archive.org/web/20190414003210id_/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/canvas-tags.html) to the `Canvas` object, and use that:

```
self.__canvas.create_text(350, lineVotes,
                          text=str(likesPrinted),
                          font=("calibri", 30), fill="#66FF99", anchor=E,
                          tag="some_tag")
```

And then pass the tag to the `delete()` method instead of the object ID:

```
self.__canvas.delete("some_tag")
```

The name of a tag can be any string that does not contain white space or periods.

Tags are more powerful because you can give the same one to multiple objects and then act on them as a group. Conversely, an object can have more than one tag attached to it by specifying a tuple of them: i.e. `tag=("1234", "@special", "posn:13,42")` in the constructor call.

To make this happen when a `Button` is clicked, you would need to also define a function or method that makes a call to one of the above `Canvas` methods when it's called. Then, when creating the button widget, specify its name via the `command=` configuration option.

For example (within a `class` definition):

```
class Class:
    ...

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.text_id = self.__canvas.create_text(350, lineVotes, text=str(likesPrinted),
                                                 font=("calibri", 30), fill="#66FF99", 
                                                 anchor=E)
        self.delete_btn = Button(root, text="Delete text", command=self.delete_text)
        self.delete_btn.pack()
    
    def delete_text(self):
        """ Delete the canvas text object. """
        if self.text_id:
            self.__canvas.delete(self.text_id)
            self.text_id = None  # To avoid multiple deletions.
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of deleting the text of canvas you can make blank or re-write with help of `canvas.itemconfig(text_id_name, text="strg text you want to change")`

```
def start():
    canvas.itemconfig(text_id, text="Hello World")


start_btn = Button(text="Start", command=start)

text_id = canvas.create_text(text="Default Text To Start"))
```

**Output**

On start button click it'll change to Hello World.