# Why won't it let me delete this string or pack it python

Tags: python, string, canvas, time, tkinter

I am trying to make a timer which counts down to a specified time says "Click me" deletes the prompt and then continues. I'm trying to use time.sleep to keep the prompt up for 1 second then delete it but it keeps giving me an error that neither string nor int have the command delete, destroy, etc. Does anyone know why this problem is occurring. Thanks for any help in advance

```
from datetime import datetime
from tkinter import *
import time
tk = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(tk, width=400, height=400)
canvas.pack()

selected_date = datetime(2017,3,24,22,22)
me = Label(tk, font=('Times',45))
me.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)
me.pack()

def countdown() :

    s = (selected_date - datetime.now()).seconds 
    me['text']=str(s) + " seconds until click" 
    if s == 0:
         text1 = str(canvas.create_text(200, 200, text="CLICK NOW", font=('Times',45)))

         text1.delete()
         time.sleep(1)


    canvas.after(1000, countdown) 


canvas.after(1000, countdown) 
tk.mainloop()
```

Thanks for any help in advance. I am not sure why it continues to give me this error

Comment: I don't know tkinter, but it seems like you should be removing something from the canvas. `text1` is just a string representation of the canvas.

Comment: Maybe just don't call `str()`.

Comment: @Barmar.        That is what I also tried but it still gives me an error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you delete a create\_text in a canvas?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28840882/how-do-you-delete-a-create-text-in-a-canvas)

Comment: citing that int doesn't have an attribute called delete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`str` does not have `delete`. Even though it has one, because the `str` is immutable object, it will not change the string itself in-place.

- You need to use `me['text'] = ''` to reset text to delete countdown message.
- If you want to use delete CLICK NOW message, you need to save the return value of `create_text`, and pass it to `canvas.delete` method later.

---

```
def countdown() :
    s = (selected_date - datetime.now()).seconds 
    me['text']=str(s) + " seconds until click" 
    if s == 0:
        text1 = canvas.create_text(200, 200, text="CLICK NOW", font=('Times',45))
        me['text'] = ''  # to delete count down
        #### If you want to delete the 'CLICK NOW' message in a second,
        #### do the following
        # canvas.after(1000, lambda: canvas.delete(text1))
    else:
        canvas.after(1000, countdown)
```

BTW, you don't need to use `time.sleep`.

Comment: Thanks so much. This example worked. Will it runs this everyday

Comment: @Kg123, runs this everyday? what does that mean?

Comment: I made this program so it would run every single day for the same time and say "Click me" at 10:22. Will it say "click me" every day or no

Comment: @Kg123, It will not work because you hard-coded `selected_date = datetime(2017,3,24,22,22)`. You need to change the `selected_date` value in the if statement body accordingly.

Comment: How would I change it to every day.

Comment: @Kg123, Could you post a separated question? I think the original question is answered, and I don't want to make lengthy comments here.

Comment: Yes. I will tomorrow because I can't ask another for 90 minutes

Comment: I would have otherwise

Comment: @Kg123, `selected_date = datetime.now() + timedelta(days=1)` (you need to import `timedelta` from `datetime` module). Also you should declare `selected_date` a global variable to change global variable.

Comment: How would I make it for everyday. Would it be days=x?

Comment: @Kg123, the function is called using `canvas.after(1000, ...)`. So it will run every seconds. `(days=1)` should be 1 to mean next day this time.

Comment: @Kg123, Try `datetime.now()` and `datetime.now() + timedelta(days=1)` in python interactive shell.