# Print Result to Canvas Not to the shell window

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Attached is part of a GUI i have constructed in Tkinter using a canvas, hence makes it possible to insert an image in the background.
When I call the function Relay_1: the result is sent to the Python shell window.
What i would like is a text box in the canvas, and show the result (i.e print the result) on the canvas and not in the shell.
Any ideas would be appreciated.

```
import Tkinter

#Function 
def Relay_1():
 arduinoData.write(b'1')
 print ("This is a test\n")   

class ProgramGUI:
def __init__(self):

    # Creates the Main window for the program        
    self.main = tkinter.Tk()

   # Change Default ICON

    self.main.iconbitmap(self,default = 'test.ico')        

   # Create title, window size and make it a non re sizable window       
    self.main.title('Test')
    self.main.resizable(False, False)                 
    self.main.geometry('680x300')       

    self.canvas = tkinter.Canvas(self.main, width = 680, height = 300)
    self.canvas.pack()

    self.logo = tkinter.PhotoImage(file = 'test.png')
    self.canvas.create_image(0,0,image = self.logo, anchor = 'nw')

    # Create 3 Frame to group the widgets        
    self.top = tkinter.Frame(self.main)
    self.middle = tkinter.Frame(self.main)                
    self.bottom = tkinter.Frame(self.main)
```

etc etc

Comment: I have set-up a line of code as follows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tkinter canvas widget has a very simple and easy to use method to draw text called `create_text()`. You can use it this way,

```
self.canvas.create_text(10, 10, text='This is a test\n')
```

The text can be customized by passing a wide range of arguments including `font`,`fill` and `justify`. Check the full list of passable arguments here:http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.create_text-method

To add the text when the code is executed, you could create a class inside `ProgramGUI()` method:

```
def draw_text(self, text):
    self.canvas.create_text(10, 10, text=text)
```

And use it after creating an object.

Comment: Thanks for the text canvas code - works nicely !! - the next step is, how do i know pass the print value of say "This is a test" into the text argument when the function is executed ?

Comment: Thanks - Yes a function to pass the parameters. When i call the function  
     def Relay_1():
          arduinoData.write(b'1')     
          draw_text('This is a Test') , i pass the parameter "This is a Test' into the Function you suggested   i.e.  def draw_text(self,text):
     self.canvas.create_text(10, 10, text=(text)) - The issue i am having is that i get an error - draw_text() missing 1 required positional argument: 'text'   , Am i calling your function incorrectly ?

Comment: I had suggested that you put the function inside the class. However, if you want to put it outside, you need to pass the gui object as a parameter to `Relay_1()`. Something like:`Relay_1(app_object, text):  app_object.draw_text(10, 10, text=text)`. That should do it

Comment: I put the function as you suggested inside the class and moved my Relay_1 function into the class and it works great !!! - If you know how to clear the text from the text box for each time i call the function , please let me know (much appreciated) otherwise i will mark as complete.

Comment: Not sure about that. But maybe you should take a look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28840882/how-do-you-delete-a-create-text-in-a-canvas